# Drag disappears when dragged outside of its base container

Tags: javascript, interact.js

I am making an Italian learning website, but I am having difficulties doing the dragging of flash cards out of their container, as it disappears. The website is viewable on [github pages](https://breaktruth.github.io/Coniugatore-italiano/) and the code viewable on [github](https://github.com/BreakTruth/Coniugatore-italiano). Anyone any clue what to do?

```js
interact('.flash-card').draggable({
  restrict: {
    restriction: '#main',
  },
  onmove: (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
    const y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    target.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
    target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }
});

interact('#main').dropzone({
  accept: '.flash-card',
  overlap: 0.6
});
```

Comment: they don't disappear, they "push" the dimensions of their container (see the scrollbars). It's probably the container's CSS you have to fix

Comment: For future reference, it might be a good idea to copy the (relevant) code in your post, so everyone can check it instead of navigating to a different site.

Comment: @Kaddath I said the drag & drop, not that stuff overflows the containers.

Comment: they don't disappear when you try to drag them out of their container, they "push" the dimensions of their container (see the scrollbars). It's probably the container's CSS you have to fix or else it will be hard to detect the moment you cross the boundaries, and aditionnally move the element out of it as stated in Aaron's answer. Clearer like this?

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements have a strict parent-child relationship. A (normal) child will never be visible outside of its parent. The effect that you're seeing is simply clipping. The same happens when you put a 500x500 image into a 10x10 DIV.

To achieve the effect that you want, you have to turn the child into some form of "top-level" element. There are several ways to do this, the most simple is to set the position to `absolute`. Another would be to make it a child of the `body` element (or hide the element and create a clone which is a child of `body`).

If you use absolute positions, you need to understand two things: The position of the child (usually 0/0) is now "relative" to something which has a `position` not equal to `static` (the default). That means it will jump. To fix this, add the top/left of the old parent. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/All_About_The_Containing_Block

Also, the element will not consume space in your layout. That means: When it has siblings, those will move.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position